# Vessel Tracking‎ service in qgis or standalone

Tags: qgis, tracking

I'm looking for a Vessel Tracking‎ service to add it in Qgis or a standalone service. I'm interested in adding a layer above the map who does tracking  the vessels.  I find this https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais-api-services/documentation/api-service:ps02 but i'm don know if I can or how to add the API in Qgis.

Comment: Does it have to be updating or is the static state when the layer gets added enough?

Comment: Updating, can be?